# Looping something while holding down the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/U9v2H/2/

I want the numbers to increase every 100ms while holding down the mouse.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var i = 1;
$("#plus1").mousedown(function () {
    loopthis = setinterval(repeatingfunction(), 100);
}).mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(loopthis);
});

function repeatingfunction() {
    $("#testarea").append(i);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: It's `setInterval` not `setinterval`

Comment: for starters it's setInterval

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the function rather than assigning a reference to it when calling `setInterval` (you also missed the uppercase I). This:

```
loopthis = setinterval(repeatingfunction(), 100);
```

should be:

```
loopthis = setInterval(repeatingfunction, 100);
```

In your original code it's immediately executing `repeatingfunction` (because that's what `()` does), then passing the value returned by that function (nothing) to be executed when the interval is up.

Answer (score 2):

It´s spelled `setInterval`, you also invoke the repeatingfunction before setInterval is running. I dont think you want to append a new textnode but replacing the old value with the new:

```
var i = 1, loopthis;
$("#plus1").mousedown(function () {
    loopthis = setInterval(repeatingfunction, 100);
}).mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(loopthis);
});

function repeatingfunction() {
    $("#testarea").text(i);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/U9v2H/5/)

Answer (score 2):

big I on setInterval and repeatingfunction should not have () after it

```
loopthis = setInterval(repeatingfunction, 100); //notice setInterval and repeatingfunction()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U9v2H/9/)

Answer (score 2):

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U9v2H/13/)

```
var i = 1;
$("#plus1").mousedown(function () {
    loopthis = setInterval(repeatingfunction, 100);
}).mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(loopthis);
});

function repeatingfunction() {
    $("#testarea").append(i);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can see is that the numbers are being appended to `testarea`. `.text()` looks much nicer :) [see](http://jsfiddle.net/U9v2H/18/)

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `loopthis` needs to be global since it was undefined within the `mouseup` event handler.  `setinterval` needed to be changed to `setInterval` and passed an anonymous function.  Also instead of appending the value of `i` change the `html` of the `div`.

**Javascript**

```
var i = 1;
var loopthis = {};
$("#plus1").mousedown(function () {
    loopthis = setInterval(function(){repeatingfunction()}, 100);
}).mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(loopthis);
});

function repeatingfunction() {
    $("#testarea").html(i);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/U9v2H/16/

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your javascript code.

1) `setinterval` shouold be setInterval

2) `loopthis = setInterval(repeatingfunction(), 100);` should be `loopthis = setInterval(repeatingfunction, 100);`

Note the `()` in `repeatingfunction()` are not required.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9v2H/19/)